# Multimedia materials for pronunciation learning

Tags: pronunciation, ipa, articulation

I randomly found this terrific [site](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/) that contains a good structured collection of images, animations and videos to show how a sound is articulated in the German, Spanish and American English languages. I need similar resources for other languages such a Arabic, French and Persian or IPA in general . Do you know such sites?

This kind of sites usually use Flash that is not indexed well by search engines, so if you know such resources for any language, please inform the community.

Comment: Arabic
------ I recently found this [page](http://transliteration.org/quran/Pronunciation/Letters/TashP.htm) for Arabic.

Comment: This question is a bit strange because it asks for general IPA **and** some particular languages. I suggest you to either choose 1) general IPA (and no mention of Arabic, Persian, French) or 2) only Arabic, Persian, French or 3) ask separate questions for 1) and 2). I have two websites for general IPA but I am confused by your question

Comment: @Theta30 I have updated the question. Please add your two web sites.

Answer (score 2):

These are some interesting links

- [Virtual Lab, Okanagan College](http://international.ouc.bc.ca/pronunciation/)
- [The IPA by J. Dowse](http://wso.williams.edu/~jdowse/ipa.html)
- [The Speech Accent Archive](http://accent.gmu.edu/index.php) which will show you the diversity of the ways of pronunciation,
- [Saundz](http://saundz.com/) (American English)

(and a nice ogv file from [Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/Real-time_MRI_-_Speaking_%28English%29.ogv))

Comment: Sadly the first two links are broken